# Using a 2-dimensional object array

Tags: java, arrays, arrayobject, type-2-dimension

This is my 2-dimensional array:

```
String[][] theMaze = new String[row][column];
```

How to use it in this method?

```
public void ruteToX(String[][] theMaze){
    // call theMaze and process in this method
}
```

Comment: What should be inside?

Comment: Are you planning to pass the array to that method?

Comment: yes, mr. mathew. that's array filled with value in main. And than how to call that array already filled in method ruteToX?

Comment: Look at my example to check how have I passed the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question in the right sense.

I'll show you an example of passing an array to the method `ruteToX(...)`.

```
public class Example
{

String[][] theMaze = new String[5][5];
public void ruteToX(String[][] theMaze)
{ 
//call theMaze and process in this method 
}

public static void main(....)
{
   Example ob=new Example();
   ob.ruteToX(ob.theMaze);
   //passed the value of reference or the pointer to the function ruteToX(...)
}
}
```

How is it passed?

When you pass an array, the value of it's `pointer or reference` in the memory is passed which means if you make any changes to the parameter array in the method, the actual array will also face the same changes (since they are the same-same reference).

Answer (score -3):

When passing in the array, in the previous method (whatever is running before 'ruteToX') call the method and pass the array in using just the variable name.

```
 public void previousMethod(){
   ruteToX(theMaze);
}    

public void ruteToX(String[][] theMaze){
    // call theMaze and process in this method
}
```

EDIT:
In addition, once in the method you can either use the array as is or create a new array equal to the original array.

```
public void ruteToX(String[][] theMaze){
        String[][] secondMaze = theMaze; 
    }
```

Comment: I don't agree with `create a new array equal to the original array`.

Comment: @MathewsMathai agreed it is not an good decision in a good amount of examples however I wanted to offer more than one option.

Comment: It's not about decision. ` String[][] secondMaze = theMaze;` doesn't creat a new array. the new array object you have created has the same reference since you are using `=`.

Comment: And so if yoh make a change to `secondMaze`, the original array will also face the same change.

Comment: You could use `Arrays.copyOf()` or `theMaze.clone()` to create a new array with the same values as the original array.